# Java applet refresh?

Tags: java, applet

I'm not even sure how to title this problem.

But basically this is a maze program, it generates a maze with specified parameters and it works pretty well for what it is. The problem is when it gets done creating the maze and setting all path tiles to white it refreshes and the grid stays there, but the path tiles disappear.

This is it when it has finished generated calling reDrawPath:
[image]
And this is it immediately after it finishes calling reDrawPath:
[image]
also not calling reDrawPath at all doesn't help, same outcome.

```
static final int border = 0;
static final int path = 1;
static final int wall = 2;

static final int cellSize = 15; // min 3
static final int cellSizeMask = (cellSize-1)/2;

static final int gridSizeh = 52; //grid gridSize (max 52)
static final int gridSizev = 52;

static final int choice = 1; // choice of algorithm (1-3)


public static int tx =1; //starting coords
public static int ty = 1; 

public static int var;
public static int varP;

public static Point[][] cords = new Point [gridSizeh][gridSizev]; // cords for each cells 
public static int tile[][] = new int [gridSizeh][gridSizev];      // if the cell will be a path, wall, or border
public static int Record[][] = new int [gridSizeh][gridSizev];



public void paint(Graphics g)   
{
    setCells(); //assigns starting grid values
    drawGrid(g); //draws the grid
    drawPath(g,tx,ty); //initial starting cord

    while(var != 16) //if the maze isnt finished then keep creating it
    {
        Checks();
        setTile(g);
    }

    if(var == 16) //when the maze is finished set all path cells to white and print done
    {
        reDrawPath(g); //redraws all path tiles to white (originally green)
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}


public static void drawGrid(Graphics g) //draws grid
{
    Expo.setBackground(g, Expo.gray);
    for(int p = 0; p<gridSizeh; p++)
        for(int k = 0; k<gridSizev; k++)
        {   
            if(tile[p][k] == border) // If the cell is a border, set to dark red
                Expo.setColor(g,Expo.darkRed);
            else                     // if not a border set all cells to black by default
                Expo.setColor(g,Expo.black);
            Expo.fillRectangle(g,(int)cords[p][k].getX()-cellSizeMask,(int)cords[p][k].getY()-cellSizeMask, (int)cords[p][k].getX()+cellSizeMask, (int)cords[p][k].getY()+cellSizeMask);

        }   
}
public static void setCells() // set initial values for grid
{
    for(int p = 0; p<gridSizeh; p++)
        for(int k = 0; k<gridSizev; k++) // set all cells to walls by default
        {   
            cords[p][k] = new Point((p+1)*cellSize,(k+1)*cellSize);
            tile[p][k] = wall;
        }
    for(int p = 0; p<gridSizeh; p++)
        for(int k = 0; k<gridSizev; k++) // if a cell is on the outer edge, set it to a border cell
        {   
            tile[p][0] = border;
            tile[p][gridSizev-1] = border;
            tile[0][k] = border;
            tile[gridSizeh-1][k] = border;
        }
}

public static void reDrawPath(Graphics g) //set all path cells to white
{
    for(int p = 1; p<gridSizeh-1; p++)
        for(int k = 1; k<gridSizev-1; k++)
        {   
            if(tile[p][k] == path)
            {
                drawRecursed(g, p, k);

            }
            Expo.delay(1);
        }
}

public static void drawPath(Graphics g, int x, int y) //sets tile path and color green
{
    Expo.setColor(g,Expo.green);
    tile[x][y] = path;
    Expo.fillRectangle(g,(int)cords[x][y].getX()-cellSizeMask,(int)cords[x][y].getY()-cellSizeMask, (int)cords[x][y].getX()+cellSizeMask, (int)cords[x][y].getY()+cellSizeMask);
}
public static void drawRecursed(Graphics g, int x, int y) // sets tile to white
{
    Expo.setColor(g,Expo.white);
    Expo.fillRectangle(g,(int)cords[x][y].getX()-cellSizeMask,(int)cords[x][y].getY()-cellSizeMask, (int)cords[x][y].getX()+cellSizeMask, (int)cords[x][y].getY()+cellSizeMask);
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). ..

Comment: .. 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).